# How to pass seleced raw data to another page with the Url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application I am using a dynamic datatable ,[image]

How can I pass the selected **Employee Id** to another page when the **Delete** is clicked ??

I am using **C# Function**:

```
try
{
    CommonClass CC = new CommonClass();
    DataTable dt = CC.GetAllDetails("AllEmployee");

    //Building an HTML string.
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    //Table start.
    html.Append("<table  class='table table-striped table-hover' id='sample_2'>");

    //Building the Header row.
    html.Append("<thead>");
    html.Append("<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<th>");
        html.Append(column.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</th>");
    }

    html.Append("<th>");
    html.Append("Delete");
    html.Append("</th>");
    html.Append("</tr>");
    html.Append("</thead>");
    html.Append("<tbody>");

    //Building the Data rows.
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
            html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        }

        html.Append("<td>");
        html.Append("<a href='DeleteEmployee.aspx?Employee_Id'>");
        html.Append("Delete");
        html.Append("</a>");
        html.Append("</td>");
    }

    html.Append("</tbody>");
    //Table end.
    html.Append("</table>");

    //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
}
```

so far my url looks `DeleteEmployee.aspx?Employee_Id` , how can i get the selected employee id with this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to append also the employee using using this code:

```
html.Append("<a href='DeleteEmployee.aspx?Employee_Id=" + row["EmployeeID"] + "'>");
```

or if you are using C#6+, use string interpolation.

```
html.Append($"<a href='DeleteEmployee.aspx?Employee_Id={row["EmployeeID"]}'>");
```